# The Quantity of things in one table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have got two different tables

- dogs (id , name)
- dogs_pref (id_dog, preference(only one) )
- preferences (one dog can have 0 , 1 , 2 preferences in text format)

The task is creating two different requests

1st : Create the request which showed dogs with preferences (one or more)
2nd : Create the request which showed quantity of preferences per dog

1st:

```
SELECT dogs.Name, dogs_pref.id_dog, dogs_pref.preference
FROM dogs
LEFT JOIN dogs_pref
ON dogs.Id=dogs_pref.id_dog
where dogs_pref.preference >= 1
ORDER BY dogs.Id;
```

2nd:

Here is the big question how to write it in simplest way
????

Comment: what db system are working on?

Comment: You say you have two tables, and you list three. Please clarify.

Comment: Based on my experience in the OP's previous question, this is going to lead to a world of pain.

Comment: MatBailie, do not worry . Everything is good :) I have got two tables - dogs and dogs_pref. Preferences is an explanation of column of 2nd table

Comment: So don't put three bullet points in your list, last one should be separated from the others. Presenting this way is confusing.

Comment: Yes its my false ((( . So what about 1st my example

Comment: Have you seen my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dogs.id, sum(to_number(dogs_pref.preference))
FROM dogs
LEFT JOIN dogs_pref
ON dogs.Id=dogs_pref.id_dog
group by dogs.id;
```